# Ubuntu 10.04 LAMP installation

Tags: ubuntu, lamp

I have tried to install a LAMP server on my Ubuntu 10.04 (home) installation by typing this into the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

However, afterwards, when I point my browser towards `http://localhost` I get:

> 403 Forbidden error.

I tried multiple times to change the permissions of the `/var/www/` folder by right clicking it and setting the permissions to read and write for my user, but it just goes back to what it was after I close the options window.

How can I access the LAMP server from my browser?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're missing an `index.html` file. Ubuntu's Apache install defaults to not enabling `Options +Indexes`, so you have to have an index document.

Answer (score 0):

Please check firewall access for port 80, could be because of that.

https://www.cloudjojo.com/how-to-install-lamp-server-on-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score -2):

Change the permissions of the directory `var` and its all files and subfolders from command prompt as root.

It should work – if not, then you have to reconfigure phpMyAdmin's main configuration file.

Comment: So, how should one change the permissions exactly?